# Check a scheduled task if exist using javascript

Tags: javascript, jscript, wscript.shell

```js
function schtasks() {
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell.run("schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn whatever /tr \"" + "C:\\",false);
    }
```

I have created this javascript code to insert a new tasksheduler,I wana make a task checking if exist before add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the tasks list using `schtasks /query`. If you make `.run` await the command, it will return the received error code.

```
function schtasks() {
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var ret = shell.run("schtasks /query /tn whatever", 0, true);
  if(!ret){
    //task doesn't exist, or something else went wrong
    shell.run("schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn whatever /tr \"" + "C:\\", 0);
  }else{
    //task exists
  }
}
```